# How to add Roku RAF to openrokn?

Tags: ads, roku, preroll

I am trying to find out how to add the Roku RAF to openrokn. The coding is a bit different since everything is in one main file. Can someone possibly give me some tips on this? I have a channel to submit that needs pre-roll.

Does this go at the top of the brs file:
Library "Roku_Ads.brs"

Does it matter where in the brs file the following items are placed within the code?

```
adIface = Roku_Ads()

adIface.setAdUrl(myAdUrl)

adPods = adIface.getAds()

shouldPlayContent = adIface.showAds(adPods)
```

I was going to add it after the playvideocontent line but it's coded differently so I need some guidance.

I'd appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `Library` on top.

Did you say "pre-roll" ad? Then you should put the RAF code just before playing the main video, naturally.